# Case-control cox regression

Tags: cox-model, case-control-study

I have a survival data on approximately 6 million observations.
The "failure" I'm dealing with is very rare - about 0.5% has the event of interest.

I have three questions:

1. Can I perform a case-control analysis with Cox regression?
2. If the answer is yes - do I just need to sample, let's say, 10 controls for each case, and then run a "regular" Cox regression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. No.

What you probably want is a case-cohort analysis, where you weight the selected observations according to their selection probabilities: a weight of 1 for cases and approximately 20 for controls.  The 'approximately 20' comes from 0.5% of cases -> 5% of control -> 1 in 20 non-cases selected.

Operationally, in R you can use `survival::cch` or `survey::twophase` and `survey::svycoxph` and I think there are implementations in Stata and SAS.

If you just ignore the sampling, as you would with a case-control logistic regression, you get slightly biased hazard ratios and a badly biased baseline hazard curve.